# ¿Cómo formatear una fecha que se obtiene de una consulta a la bd Oracle en java?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, date, microservices

Tengo el siguiente query que regresa una lista de datos, el campo **fechaRegistro** que esta mapeado como tipo String  me regresa la fecha en este formato  **2023-05-26 07:21:00** y quiero que se muestre en este otro formato

> 26/05/23

este es mi servicio y mi query

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> getControl() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        List<ControlEntity> query = new ArrayList<ControlEntity>();
        try {
            query = repository.findQuery();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");
            response.put("success", false);
            response.put("error", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        response.put("success", true);
        response.put("data", query);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }




@Query(value = "SELECT C.ID, C.DESCRIPCION, C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIO, C.FECHA_REGISTRO FROM CONTROL C", 
    nativeQuery = true)
    List<ControlEntity> findQuery();
```

Intenté usar TO_DATE de esta manera

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT C.ID, C.DESCRIPCION, C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIO, TO_DATE(CE.FECHA_REGISTRO, 'dd/MM/yy') AS FECHA_REGISTRO FROM CONTROL C", 
    nativeQuery = true)
    List<ControlEntity> findQuery();
```

pero me regresa la fecha asi :

```
2023-05-26 00:00:00
```

como se podría cambiar el formato?

Comment: ya intentaste preguntar como cambiar el formato para la consulta de SQL? posiblemente allí esta lo que buscas

Comment: veo qu tratas de convertir una fecha a... una fecha! tal vez quieras convertirla a cadena de caracteres `to_char(sysdate,'dd/MM/YY') `

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        //seteando la fecha
        Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
                .parse("aqui va tu fecha");
        //el objeto dt tienen tu fecha formateada ahora 
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(CrearFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha mal ingresada");
        return false;
    }
```